# Onclick button timeout javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me get started with a button timeout feature.  All I want is a button (when clicked) it becomes inactive for 2 seconds.  After which it is active again.

Comment: get familiar with the window.setTimeout(funcName,milliseconds), where you call a functon, which enables your button after 2000ms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="click" id="click" onclick="foo(this);"/>​

function foo(obj) {
    obj.disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        obj.disabled = false;
    }, 2000);
}​
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BvYwr/1)

`window.setTimeout` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout):

> Executes a code snippet or a function after specified delay.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but since `disabled` is a property and not an attribute, pretty sure you can (and should) use `true` and `false` as values.

Comment: @Xeon06. It's new spec, for HTML5 if I'm not wrong, you're right. Updted.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the feedback, extremely helpful as I try to expand my js knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Start of with:

```
<button>Click me!</button>
```

Add an event:

```
<button onClick="...">Click me!</button>
```

Now we need to put something in place of that `...`.

`this` can be used to mean "the button that was just clicked"

`this.disabled` can be set to `true` or `false` to disable (or re-enable) the button.

`setTimeout(function() {...},2000);` executes the anonymous function after two seconds have passed (or as near as the timer resolution allows).

Again, need to put something in the `...`. I've already told you how to re-enable the button.

Although, since `this` isn't terribly reliable inside anonymous functions, it's probably better to start with `var t = this;` and use `t` to mean the button.

With all that in place, you have:

```
<button onClick="var t = this; t.disabled = true; setTimeout(function() {t.disabled = false;},2000);">Click me!</button>
```

Done. I hope this explanation was helpful.

PS. To those who are against inline event handlers:

1. This is an example
2. The OP is a beginner
3. An inline event is good enough

Comment: Though he's a beginner you don't **must** write inline scripts... :)

Comment: I was just about to comment about the use of an inline event handler. [Okay.](http://okayface.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The function `setTimeout` allows you to specify a function to be called after an amount of milliseconds has passed. In this case, I passed in an anonymous function, that is, a function that does not have a name that is used for the sole purpose of re-enabling my button after 2 seconds.

```
var mybutton = document.getElementById("mybutton");
mybutton.onclick = function() {
    mybutton.disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        mybutton.disabled = false;
    }, 2000);
};​
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9zSH/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout() function in javascript. Something like

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<input id="test" type="submit" value = "clickme" onclick="deactivatefunc()">
<script type="text/javascript">

 function deactivatefunc()
 {
    var btn = document.getElementById("test");
    btn.disabled = true;
    var mytimer = setTimeout(activate,2000);
 }

function  activate () {
    var btn = document.getElementById("test");
    btn.disabled = false;
}
</script>
</body> 

</html>
```